# Цикл для скрипта, python

Tags: python, время, клавиатура, while, мышь

Нужно чтобы скрипт зажимал букву d на n-сек + Лкм, потом зажимал букву a на n-сек + Лкм. И при нажатии допустим F7 - скрипт переставал зажимать кнопки, но ждал опять ждал активацию на пробел.
Помогите пожалуйста, скорее всего задаю банальный вопрос, но заранее огромное спасибо <3 !
Вот код который у меня на данный момент :

```
import keyboard
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from offset import *

while True:
    keyboard.wait("space")
    for k in range(timer):
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press("d")
        mouse.click(Button.left)
        print(timer)
        timer -= 1
        if timer == 0:
            keyboard. release("d")
            break
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F7"):
            keyboard. release("d")
            break
```

Таймер принтует вот это

```
import keyboard
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()
timer = 150
```

это другой файл в папке со скриптом.

Comment: Что такое timer, и что он принтует?

Comment: break - выход из цикла. Что приводит к завершению кода